# How to find the value of a variable using solution of Simultaneous equations?

Tags: equation-solving, functions

I have to find the value of `p` where

```
p=a1*x+b2*y;
```

using the solution of the equation

```
a1*x+b1*y=4
a2*x+b2*y=6
a1=2;a2=5;b1=-4;b2=2;
Solve[{a1*x+b1*y==0;a2*x+b2*y==0},{x,y}]
```

How to find the value of `p` using this solutions of x and y?

Comment: You give two different sets of equations. Using the first: `With[{a1 = 2, a2 = 5, b1 = -4, b2 = 2},  p = a1*x + b2*y  /. Solve[ {a1*x + b1*y == 4, a2*x + b2*y == 6}, {x, y}][[1]]]`

Comment: Here how can i see the values of x and y together? Means solve value of x and y.

Answer (score 1):

In response to your comment, assign an intermediate variable

```
With[{a1 = 2, a2 = 5, b1 = -4, b2 = 2},
 solxy = Solve[
    {a1*x + b1*y == 4, a2*x + b2*y == 6},
    {x, y}][[1]]; 
 p = a1*x + b2*y /. solxy]

(*  2  *)
```

The values of x and y are

```
solxy

(*  {x -> 4/3, y -> -(1/3)}  *)
```

Answer (score 0):

And the third variant, note the transformation

```
fun1[x_] := a1*x + b1*y - 4
fun2[x_] := a2*x + b2*y - 6
a1 = 2; a2 = 5; b1 = -4; b2 = 2;
solP = {x, y} /. FindInstance[fun1[x] == 0 && fun2[x] == 0, {x, y}]
```

> {{4/3, -(1/3)}}

```
ContourPlot[{fun1[x], fun2[x]}, {x, -5, 5}, {y, -5, 5}, 
Epilog -> {Red, PointSize[Large], Point[solP]}]
```

[image]